# Print last number in sequence of numbers in python

Tags: python

I have several sets of semi identical lists lists e.g.

```
x=[nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,9][nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,8,9][nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,7,8,9][nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,6,7,8,9][nan,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9][1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

#So I want to print the last number of the last list. I have tried:
print(x[-1])

#it returns:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
#I have tried:
x2 = []
x2.append(x[-1])
print(x2[1])
#Returns the same thing
#Have also tried x[-1][-1] but that returns the error "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable."
```

Comment: Try `x[-1][-1]`

Comment: Show us how are you assiging the X. with your code we will get: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Answer (score 0):

if you know the dimension of your lists, then you know how deep to go, in your case you need to go 2 levels deep so you should try `x[-1][-1]` if your list were 3 levels deep you would need to try `x[-1][-1][-1]` and so on.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it responds with "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable."